# Why does my android manifest file report errors?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm suddenly getting a lot of odd errors in my android manifest file.  It is still able to compile my application and run!  But I know that these errors must be affecting the project.

I have tried to "clean" my project through a full new build and also by forcing a sync with my gradle files.  But alas, these errors persist.  These errors are new, in that yesterday there were no errors found in this file.  I did not make any significant changes to the file nor did I move it out of it's core folder.

I am just confused as to why this error is still appearing.  Any ideas?

Problems in android manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myCom.com.myapp"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- social auth -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- google -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="myCom.com.myapp.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="myCom.com.myapp.SmileListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_smile_list"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- twitter -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWESABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="twitter-oauth"
                    android:scheme="myCom.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="myCom.com.myapp.SmileDisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_smile_display" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="myCom.com.myapp.Login"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what do they errors say?

Comment: over the schema: it says "URI is not registered".... over "launchmode", "versionname" and "versionCode" it states that "<launchmode> is not allowed here"

Comment: is your manifestfile complete, please post your full manifestfile information

Comment: The LaunchMode is only aplicable for Activities cannot be placed under  <Manifest  />  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode   has more information about it

Comment: please remove this line android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: i removed that and the other errors are still there.........

Comment: in your file, are there leading spaces or empty lines befor the xml tag?

Comment: VersionCode, versionname - still show errors.  in addition, errors are still shown under "android:backup", "android:icon", "meta-data", "launchmode" and "data" tags in the document.  I checked, no there are no additional spaces or empty lines above the xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in main tag `manifest` .
Put somewhere on your `activity` tag where you want to that `activity` to be TOP and SINGLE .
This what google doc say about `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target
>   task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to
>   its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the
>   activity.
>   Refer [Google document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more option

Comment: VersionCode, versionname - still show errors.  in addition, errors are still shown under "android:backup", "android:icon", "meta-data", "launchmode" and "data" tags in the document.  I checked, no there are no additional spaces or empty lines above the xml tag.